# Xamarin Native Binding: Failed resolution of

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, aar

I have been trying to bind an AAR library in Xamarin and I was able to build it with few warnings.
But as soon as I try to use an activity from the resulted DLL, I get this error:

```
Failed resolution of: Lcom/spectratech/lib/R$layout;
```

I have checked the library and it has all the resources present in res folder and working in Android Studio.

I have tried every solution available on the internet like Clean and Build and enabling Multidex but could not make it work.
Resources are not being loaded from the library.

Any suggestions?

Comment: so basically you are unable to use the library resources

Comment: not sure, what should i do?

Comment: When do you get this error R$layout one

Comment: When it tries to access some resources in library (OnCreate)

Comment: Do you have any package/jar you added in AS but not added in vs?

Comment: @Billy yes there is one jar google's Gauva which is a dependency i did not include in binding project because when I include it gives loads of errors like 
`Error while processing type '[Class] com.google.common.collect.AbstractBiMap.EntrySet': Type 'K' was not found`.

Comment: Does it work by install the nuget package?`Install-Package Xamarin.Google.Guava -Version 23.2.0`